# Not able to update account using rest API

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest, code, patch

I am trying to update account record using Rest ,but i am getting error

```
**CALLOUT_RESPONSE [17]|System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]**
```

Code

```
global class AccountUpdate{
static String sfdcURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm(); 
//@future(callout=true)
global static void execute() {
    //Make sure your Salesforce instance URL is added in remote site settings
    // String sfdcURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm(); 
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
    Http h = new Http();
    req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v46.0/sobjects/account/0012x000002XVJo?_HttpMethod=PATCH');

    req.setBody('{ "rating" : warm }');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
}
```

}

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error because your JSON is invalid. You have to quote string values in JSON.

This code should be replaced by a single line:

```
update new Account(Id = '0012x000002XVJo', Rating = 'Warm');
```

It should not be `global`;  it doesn't need a Remote Site Setting (so long as My Domain is turned on); it shouldn't get the Base URL twice; it shouldn't hard-code an Id.

Comment: issue with json. thanks its working now